# Posting a link to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a user who can manage some Facebook Page. I've got access token with all permissions, including publish_actions as written [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/#pubperms).
When I send a POST request from Graph API Explorer to `<page-id>/feed` specifying `message` and `access_token` of course, my post appears in Page Feed and author of this post is Page. But when I send a POST request with `link` instead of `message` it appears in 'recent publications from others' with my name.
What have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you the admin of the page?

Comment: Yes. I'm the creator of that page. And I can send `message` to this page

Comment: By message do you mean comments or posts? Because whatever the case is it should not appear in recent publications from others. Or may be you must be logging in as different user than the page admin user.

Comment: I ment that I can send requests with `message` field. Posts

Comment: I can send posts from Facebook to that Page. And I can send messages from API and it will appear as Page's post. But if I post link with the same way from API it appears as User's post

Comment: Are you using a page access token retrieved from a graph call to /me/accounts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing. If I send a `message` to `<page-id>/feed` it will work fine. But if I send a `link` to the same endpoint it posts on the